# Low battery. Android behavior

Tags: android, battery

Is there any specific behavior of Android OS, when the battery is low?
For example, disabling Bluetooth module, or killing apps/services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most android OS's include a Power saving mode which can be set to kick in when your battery life hits a certain threshold I.e 30%.

This allows you to turn off WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS, adjust brightness etc. automatically once this threshold has been past.

For this to take effect the Power saving mode needs to be enabled and settings specified. I believe this is usually made available within the settings menu of most android OS's but I have heard that the "Ice Cream Sandwich" OS has it hidden away out of reach of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. However, some handset manufacturers try to save that last bit of power by e.g. lowering the screen brightness (Samsung). Also, there are a lot of third party apps that manages all kinds of settings based on location, time of day, etc. Perhaps some of them can trigger certain actions when the battery level gets too low, but I haven't really tried any of them myself.